# Vue3 Masonry Layout

Tags: vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 and Macyjs for layouts and I want the image to load like the second one. what should I do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlT1V.gif)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxuQ.gif)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import Macy from 'macy'

const macyInstance = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  macyInstance.value = Macy({
    container: '.wrapper',
    trueOrder: true,
    waitForImages: true,
  })
})

function load() {
  macyInstance.value.runOnImageLoad(() => {
    macyInstance.value.recalculate(true)
  }, true)
}

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <template v-for="(item) in data" :key="item.id">
      <img
        :src="`http://127.0.0.1:1337${item.i.formats.small.url}`"
        style="width: 100%;"
        @load="load"
      />
    <template/>
  <div/>
<template/>
```